# How to comunicate with an flask RESTful api

Tags: python, api, backend, communication, flask-restful

I'm currently building a webapp that runs on a flask RESTful api. My question is how can I best communicate in the frontend with the backend.
For example, I have an endpoint /products which has a get method to display all products and a post method to create a new product. How can I determine when which method is executed. [Code of the methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjHm0.png)

Comment: This is a very basic question. What have you researched about REST so far?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.